# State usage in react-native material dropdown

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on a react-native app. It's a todo application where you can add tasks, assign to others and choose due date of the task itself.
I'm using react-native material dropdown, for displaying the possible assignee(s), and once selected I would send the data to firebase.
This is my code for DropdownComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

class DropdownComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      assignee: 'Initial state',
    data: [{
      value: 'Fruit',
    }, {
      value: 'Vegetable',
    }, {
      value: 'Fruit',
    }],
    value: ''
    }
  }



  handleAssigneePicked = value => {
    console.log("Changed state")
    this.setState({ assignee: value()})
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <Dropdown
        data={this.state.data}
        value={this.state.assignee}
        onchangeText={this.handleAssigneePicked}
      />
    );
  }
}


export default DropdownComponent;
```

And i'm rendering it in my Main component, like this:

```
<DropdownComponent
            />
```

Now when I visit the Main component, where it renders the DropdownComponent, it also shows initial state, but doesn't console.log anything, can something shed some light on my issue?

Comment: A typo in the callback handler, `onChangeText` perhaps?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, good catch! Getting `value is not a function (In 'value'(); 'value' is "Vegetable"); any ideas about this one

Comment: Your setState call, it should be `this.setState({ assignee: value })` sans the parens since `value` isn't a function.

Comment: Fantastic, this seems to be working, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coding like hurry burry.

Change the dropdown props as

```
onChangeText={this.handleAssigneePicked}
```

instead of

```
onchangeText={this.handleAssigneePicked}
```

and bind the handlerAssigneePicked() method in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAssigneePicked = this.handleAssigneePicked.bind(this);
}
```

is it acceptable? Yes, upvote